# Predicting decay time of a resonant bandpass filter?

Tags: filter, resonance, band-pass, digital-filter

In a typical resonant bandpass filter, resonance is set as none at 0 and full at 1, such that the filter rings infinitely at 1 and not at all at 0.

If there is a two-pole resonant bandpass filter, with an impulse excitation to a maximum amplitude of "1" and resonance setting between 0 and 1:

What is the mathematical equation that would allow you to predict the decay time of the resonant filter based on its resonance setting? For example, to an arbitrary level of "1/e"? ie. To 36.7879% its original amplitude?

Thanks.

**Update June 3, 2018 @ 5:17 PM**

Thanks to some good answers below, I now better understand the problem as follows:

- I need an equation to solve for Q or ζ of the filter based on an input of time (where that time represents seconds to reach 1/e amplitude relative to a starting 1 amplitude).
- The bandpass filter will only be needed in an "underdamped" condition, ie. Q>0.5.

Thanks again. This has been very informative and I think this should be a clearer and more answerable question.

Comment: Do you know of the [Q factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor)? Your "resonance setting" comes across as an attempt to re-invent the same concept.

Comment: Thanks @jms! Very helpful question. Instead of using a "resonance factor" to set the filter, I can set it by bandwidth in octaves. From wiki: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e8d004126524d7bedf71098dc6d9c0ebe5935322 , I can solve for Q from BW & fo. Q is then the number of oscillations to reach e^-pi relative to original amplitude. Thus Q/fo = time to reach e^-pi amplitude. I am interested in calculating time to reach 1/e amplitude. So I would then just need the general amplitude decay equation to bridge that gap. Any help? Thanks again!

Comment: Is amplitude decay over time based on y=1/c^x? If so I can calculate c given that data (time to reach e^-pi amplitude). With c, I can then find any amplitude at any time. Is this correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andy's answer is good, but it can be generalized. For the transfer function:

$$H(s)=\frac{2\zeta\omega_n s}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_n s+\omega_n^2}$$

the inverse Laplace for all of the three mentioned cases have the same exponential decaying term in them:

$$exp(-\zeta\omega_n t)$$

That will be the envelope of the whole response. The rest of the time response is either of the form \$\sin{t}+\cos{t}\$ (oscillating, for underdamped), or \$\sinh{t}+\cosh{t}\$ (for overdamped), or a fixed term as a function of time, involving \$\omega_n\$ and \$\zeta\$.

If you really want them in full, here they are:

- overdamped:

$$h(t)=\exp(-\omega_n\zeta t)\left[2\omega_n\zeta\cosh(\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\omega_nt)-\frac{2\omega_n\zeta^2\sinh(\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}\omega_nt)}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\right]$$

- critically damped:

$$h(t)=\exp(-\omega_n\zeta t)\left[2\omega_n\zeta(1-\omega_n\zeta t)\right]$$

- underdamped:

$$h(t)=\exp(-\omega_n\zeta t)\left[2\omega_n\zeta\cos(\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\omega_nt)-\frac{2\omega_n\zeta^2\sin(\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\omega_nt)}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\right]$$

---

If you need to find the time when the *envelope* (alone) reaches a certain value x, then it's as simple as:

$$\exp(-\omega_n\zeta t)=x => -\omega_n\zeta t=\log x => t=-\frac{\log x}{\omega_n\zeta}$$

> *Update:* This is only valid for the *underdamped* case, as there is a clear case of an oscillating term -- cos()-sin() -- multiplied by an inverse exponential. For the other two cases, it's impossible to do it analitically, as the time, t, is in more than one term, and that term is not oscillating, but either linearly variable (critically damped), or exponential (overdamped), so simplification is not possible. Also see the last pargraph.

Don't forget that, in all three cases, there is an additional term that can be factored out: \$2\omega_n\zeta\$, which gives the amplitude of the initial decay.

Note the \$\omega_n\$ in there, which tells you that the higher the frequency the higher the amplitude(!). This is related to an impulse that has the area of 1 (e.g. for a 1ms impulse, the amplitude is 1000). If you want to consider only a unity amplitude impulse, of zero duration (unity amplitude Dirac), then the extra term can be omitted (discarded).

---

*Caveat emptor*: the shape of the decay will *not* correspond to the final result in the case of \$\zeta\$>1, due to the hyperbolic functions! If the sinh() term would have been just like the cosh() term, the whole expression would have been reduced to an exp(-t), but sinh() is multiplied by \$\frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}}\$, which means that the whole cosh()-sinh() term will "explode" if it were all by itself. Being multiplied by the exp() in front limits the response, but the envelope is no longer the same (contrary to the underdamped case). Here is what I mean:

[image: comp]

`G1, G2, G3` together with `C1, C2` form the bandpass filter having `V(o)` as the output. `V(exp)` is the exponential decay (together with the \$\omega_n\zeta t\$ term, see `Rpar=2*z*wn` in `B1`), `V(sinh_cosh)` is the cosh()-sinh() term, `V(test)` is the multiplication of the previous two, compared with `V(o)` in the lower-most plot (they are the same). The upper two plots show the individual responses of the envelope and of the hyperbolic term -- this is what I meant when I said it "explodes", it goes to \$-\infty\$. And here is why I said that the envelope will not match the response, only by itself, due to the hyperbolic term:

[image: env]

Neither the output (blue trace), or its absolute value (black) will match the envelope alone (red). Which means that the solution above will not work, and the whole expression of the impulse response has to be considered, which means that, sadly, you're out of luck, since the expression contains the time, t, in both the envelope and the hyperbolic term. Even if you were to equivalate this with its equivalents, cosh=[exp(-x)+exp(-x)]/2 (minus for sinh), you cannot apply a logarithm to each exp(), only as a whole, which means the time cannot be extracted analitically, so you're stuck to numerical methods.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I looked at the situation and I will always be dealing with the underdamped condition (Q≥1). At the resonant frequency (ie. ωn?), I believe ω=2pi*f and ζ=1/(2Q). What I lastly then need is an equation that will solve for ζ if input with a time, where that time presents seconds to decay to 1/e amplitude from an initial amplitude of 1. Can you help further to formulate this? I'd appreciate it if so! I tried putting your equation into desmos to confirm it is an amplitude equation starting from y=1 at x=0, but it didn't graph: http://desmos.com/calculator/ifkbvio6wg

Comment: I think the problem with graphing is coming from the sqrt(ζ^2-1) components. For underdamped, Q>0.5, thus ζ<1. If ζ<1, then this will always be a square root of a negative number. Was this intentional or an error? It obviously can't compute.

Comment: @mike You're right, I copy-pasted the darn mathjax and forgot to reverse 1 with \$\zeta\$ (since \$\zeta\$<1). I'll correct and also try to update with an analytical solution for your case. There is a caveat, though, I'll also add that.

Comment: Awesome thanks! If it helps, I mainly need this to be relatively accurate between 1≤Q≤~3000. After that it starts resonating almost indefinitely which is not needed. Thanks again. Looking forward to your solution!

Comment: Hahaha. Thanks concerned citizen. That was very helpful. So for time to level 1/e, it all just simplifies to: Q= T*pi*Fo, which is what I had figured out yesterday when I posted my own answer to the question myself. I just retested my project and it seems to work fine like this. There was another error in the project which I didn't see until today, and I didn't bother to retest it with that fixed today. Anyway, problem seems to be solved. Thanks a bunch. I've learned a lot!

Comment: @mike Whenever you find an answer which you consider to be the one that you were looking for, click the check mark to select it as accepted. This serves future searches to know that this particular question has an answer. It doesn't have to be this one, necessarily, but it helps others in the future, and the questions don't need to be "revived" every so often in an attempt for the OP to realize that the solution needs to be selected.

Comment: Left in a hurry, it looks like you didn't see the last part, about the overdamped reponse not being able to predict the decay due to hyperbolic functions. Be sure to read it, you probably won't like the answer, though. I'll also add some small modifications.

Comment: Like I said - I don't need an overdamped solution. This is solely for Q>0.5 ie. underdamped so it's simple enough. Thanks

Comment: @mike My bad, I misread. Still, the conclusions remain.

Answer (score 1):

A band pass filter would typically have a transfer function like this: -

$$H(s) = \dfrac{s2\zeta\omega_n}{s^2 + s2\zeta\omega_n +\omega_n^2}$$

Where \$2\zeta\$ is 1/Q

And \$\omega_n\$ is the natural resonant frequency of the filter.

For an LC bandpass filter, \$\omega_n\$ = \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$

To convert this to the time domain (due to an impulse response) there will be three time-domain solutions: -

- \$\zeta\$ < 1 (under-damped)
- \$\zeta\$ = 1 (critically-damped)
- \$\zeta\$ > 1 (over-damped)

There is, unfortunately not a one-size-fits-all solution. Life gets easier if you set \$\omega_n\$ to 1 and then look at the inverse Laplace table for the three scenarios.

---

For a **critically** damped situation (\$\zeta = 1\$): -

$$H(s) = \dfrac{2s}{s^2 + 2s +1}$$

And, using inverse Laplace tables you find the solution as: -

$$h(t)=2e^{-t}-e^{-t}\cdot \:2t$$

---

For an **underdamped** situation with \$\zeta\$ = 0.5 you get: -

$$H(s) = \dfrac{s}{s^2 + s +1}$$

And this inverse transforms to: -

$$h(t)=e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2}\right)$$

---

For an **overdamped** situation where for example \$\zeta\$ = 2 you get: -

$$H(s)=\dfrac{4s}{s^2 + 4s+1}$$

And this inverse transforms to: -

$$h(t)=4e^{-2t}\cosh \left(\sqrt{3}t\right)-\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-2t}\sinh \left(\sqrt{3}t\right)$$

---

You can use [this really good interactive calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B4s%7D%7Bs%5E%7B2%7D%2B4s%2B1%7D) instead of tables should you wish: -

[image]

> What is the mathematical equation that would allow you to predict the
>   decay time of the resonant filter based on its resonance setting?

The above formulas are the only ones I can recommend.